# Is there a way to make multiple running threads pulling data from a stream start writing that data to separate files at the exact same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I'm writing softare that records data from a number of sensors. A user should be able to press a button to start streaming and then another to start recording this data to a file. Each device has its own thread so pressing the stream button will start a thread to stream for each device, and pressing record should make all these threads start writing to files.

I've attempted to implement this by creating a new thread to start pulling samples and then using a volatile bool to tell the threads when to start writing the samples to a file.

Here is the code running inside the threads:

```
    public void streamData(CancellationToken ct, liblsl.StreamInlet inlet)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            pullSampleFromLSL(inlet);

            //start writing to file if requested
            //if(_isRecording){
            //  writeToFile()
            //} 

        }
    }
```

This method hasn't provided the accuracy I was hoping for as each file records a different timestamp for when recording was started (recorded using Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds from a set starting point). Is there a way to do this so that all the files begin at (as close to as possible) the exact same timestamp?

cheers

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are the sensor data packets coming with timestamps, and your file and your streaming end up with some sensor data packets being streamed and some sensor data packets being to the file? Or is the actual sensor data packets being completely and correctly streamed and written to the file, and only the timestamps seem to be incorrect?

Comment: @elgonzo sensor data comes in with timestamps but the start time is recorded when writeToFile is first called. Both timestamps are synchronized to the same clock.

Comment: I am sorry, but i have to admit that my confusion just grew and your problem became more unclear to me. How differs the meaning and purpose of "start time" from the sensor data timestamps? And if both "start time" and timestamps are synchronized to the same clock anyway, what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @elgonzo Sorry for being unclear -- the goal is to have all threads start recording at  the same time

Comment: How so? You explained in your question that one thread (streaming) starts when the user presses a button, and another thread (file writing) starts when the user presses another button. How does this explanation fit with your comment saying "_all threads start recording at the same time_"? I am completely lost now...

Comment: @elgonzo when I mentioned that buttons start streaming/recording from devices, I should have elaborated that each device has its own thread. Pressing the streaming button would start multiple threads, with each thread streaming from a device. The goal is to have the recording button start all these threads start writing data to their respective files at the same time.

Comment: Ah, and the first entry (or one of the entries) written to each of those files will be the "start time" which records the time when the user pressed the button. And all files should record the same "start time". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @elgonzo yeah thats it, I'll edit the question to be a bit more specific

Comment: Basically, have a variable/field/property that receives the time value when the button is being pressed (that can be done in the button click handler). Then, after this variable/field/property has been assigned the start time, start up the threads. Each thread then would access/get the same time value from that "start time" variable/field/property then...

Comment: @FYI: Disregard my former (now deleted) comments with regards to clock stability/drift. It was really, really outdated information. In the meantime, i found a study from 2008, which for server CPUs found that CPU clocks are not really suffering from drift "too much". That's why i sniped my last two comments... ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo The one issue with that is I was using the same thread to stream and record, so all the threads are already streaming. To start recording in the way you suggested would I record all the streamed data into a buffer then only write the data that comes after a certain timestamp? Ah no worries. I'm aware that the clock will only be so accurate, however it is only being used in relatively short bursts of a few hours and is the most accurate hw clock I have access to.

Comment: Again, i do not really understand what you are getting at now. What is this "_data that comes after a certain timestamp_" thing about? StackOverflow is unfortunately ill-suited to have broad and long discussions, as StackOverflow is geared towards and emphasizes the question&answer format. If you sill struggle with your problem, i suggest you first take a step back, think your problem through with a fresh head. Then, try to formulate a new question here on StackOverflow that precisely explains what you are actually trying to achieve (no vague shorthands in the explanation, please), (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) and what the current problem is you are struggling with. It feels to me the comment thread here lurches from one unclear aspect of your problem to the next unclear aspect of your problem. Keep in mind, we can (and will) pick apart your question, but we can't pick apart your mind ;-)

Comment: yeah its always good to stay objective about these things. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: How much unwanted drifting do you have? Milliseconds? Seconds? What kind of threads do you use? Thread-pool? Dedicated?

Comment: Regarding the `_isRecording` variable, is it accessed by multiple threads? If yes, are you locking around every read and write to the variable? Or have you declared the variable [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the threads are dedicated and isRecording is defined as volatile. It is written to by one thread and read by multiple. There's not a large amount of drift, but I was hoping to have a timestamp for when recording is started, and then have the timestamps of the recorded data be as close to that timestamp as possible, given the polling rate.

Comment: @Will each thread is getting time slices of around 20 msec. If you want to reduce the drifting below that then you are asking too much from the OS.

Comment: @Will - A [mcve] would be great here. It would enable us to propose a working solution.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I would use a monitor class that trought condition variables notify all thread to start.

Comment: Do you mean a [`ManualResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent) class, or you actually mean the [`Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor) with its static methods?

Comment: I'm refering to the `Monitor`. A class where synchronizations stuff are managed. I'm sure in java, but should exist something similar in C# or you can create the logic anyway writing it on your own. A condition variable holds 2 values: the first one hold the number of permitted accesses and the second one it's a queue of all threads that made a request when no permitions were available. So basically you can manage when and which threads have to start. So your button would just add to a variable the number of permissions and all your thread may run simultaneously

Comment: The intent of the `Monitor` class is to provide exclusive access to only one thread at a protected piece of code. The most primitive .NET mechanism for notifying multiple threads to start all at once is the `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: More sophisticated mechanisms are the [`Barrier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.barrier), for synchronization between worker threads, and the [`CountdownEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent), for synchronizing a controller thread based on the progress of the worker threads.